# Is comm output guaranteed sorted?

Tags: comm

Is the output of `comm` guaranteed sorted?  In my simple examples they are and that makes sense to me (how I think comm works); however, I need to `comm` very large files and worried that comm might do some black magic for very large files.

Also, can someone point me to the source of `comm`?  I've never been able to find the source for such scripts.

Thanks

Comment: Asking 2 questions at once is not a good idea, so the second one got never answered. Here it goes. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366015/how-do-i-look-at-the-source-code-for-a-command for 2 possible answers. There are several implementations of  `comm`. A commonly used one is from GNU and its source code is at http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/comm.c?h=v8.29&id=27b2b19aa8d8b30b8cb4198b2f4b54568e10a35e (newest released version as of time of writing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if your input lines are ordered in the current collating sequence. From POSIX [comm STDOUT](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html#tag_20_21_10) documentation:

> If the input files were ordered according to the collating sequence of
>   the current locale, the lines written shall be in the collating
>   sequence of the original lines.

If you guaranteed your input sorted, the `comm` output guaranteed sorted, too.

POSIX also defined that if your input is not ordered according to the collating sequence of the current locale, the `comm` output will be *unspecified*.

If you have [GNU comm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm), you can use option `--check-order` to make unsorted inputs will cause a fatal error message.

Comment: I asked ChatGPT to explain the referenced text with the following prompt :

`What does the sentence below mean, in particular the term "current locale" and "collating sequence" ?

If the input files were ordered according to the collating sequence of the current locale, the lines written shall be in the collating sequence of the original lines.`

Comment: ChatGPT's answer:

In the given sentence, "current locale" refers to the current regional or language settings of the system where the program is running. The "collating sequence" refers to the order in which characters are sorted or arranged based on their linguistic or alphabetical order.

(continued below)

Comment: So, the sentence is stating that if input files are organized or sorted based on the collating sequence of the current locale (the regional or language settings), then the lines that are written will also follow the same order. In other words, the output will be arranged in the collating sequence of the original lines, considering the language-specific sorting rules.